# Why is this code breaking jquery UI drag & drop (with isotope)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-isotope

I have a page with a grid of items. Each of these items can be dragged onto one of four divs and gets added to that div. This is done using jQuery and JQuery UI draggable/droppable.

The first isotope item can be dragged onto any of the divs. However, the 2nd & 3rd isotope items don't recognize the first droppable div, but when dragged onto the 2nd droppable div, will be added to the first droppable div.

The 4th & 5th draggable items (isotopes) don't recognize the first or second droppable div, but when dragged over the 3rd droppable, gets added to the 2nd droppable.

So somehow the droppable is getting confused as to where the items are being dropped.

When I comment out the following code, the drag and drops work properly. Any ideas as to why this code would affect the droppable areas??

```
jQuery('div.container').isotope({
 itemSelector: 'div.sub-item', 
 resizesContainer : false,
 layoutMode : 'fitColumns',
 getSortData :{ 
   fitOrder : function ($item){
    var order, 
       index = $item.index();
       if($item.hasClass('sub-item-big') && index % 2) {
            order = index +1.5;
            } else {
            order = index;
            }
        return order;
       }
   },
 sortBy : 'fitOrder'
});
```

--------------- update ------------------

After some more playing around with this, I decided to add 'destroy' the isotope upon initiating a drag.

```
  jQuery('div.sub-item').draggable({
         helper: function(){
                jQuery('div.container').isotope('destroy');
                return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body');
          }
    })
```

When I run it this way, the items are being dropped into the correct container.

The isotope documentation says their is a 'remove' function, there are two problems with that.

1) the documentation says it removes the 'specified item elements from Isotope widget and the DOM', but I don't want to remove the item from the widget or from the dom, I just want to remove the isotope functionality

2) I get an error 'cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization, attempted to call method remove' - but in this case the isotope was initialized, but possibly not on the object that was cloned??  This is above my abilities, though I'm hoping to learn.

Now that I have found one way of correcting this error, I could destroy isotope upon a drag, and then re-initialize isotope after the drag is complete, or the item is let go, but that seems to be inefficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isotope and jquery UI colliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408489/isotope-and-jquery-ui-colliding)